# AWS API Gateway + DynamoDB Role ARN Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I've tried to connect a simple db in DynamoDB with a basic API in API Gateway that I've built. I followed this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TuGyyTXPQ-U and after creating the DB, generating the role with the appropriate permissions and generating a simple get request in the API gateway I keep running into this error:

> {
>     "message": "AWS ARN for integration contains invalid action"
>   }

I get this with both post/get request in my API. Pretty new to AWS so anything would help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste your full code you are using

Comment: An export of your API would be helpful, or at least post the URI used by the integration.  Alternatively, you can PM me the API id and region or invoke URL and so I can find your API definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get that error if the action on the integration is blank or missing.  On the integration page, ensure that "Action type" is set to "Use action name" and ensure that "Action" is set to "PutItem".

Answer (score 0):

This error related with ARN Role.  Check the IAM role, and check its have dynamoDb full access permission.

NB :

1. Use IAM Role insteadof IAM User